# Condensing a Series of Internships on Resume

Tags: resume, internship

**TL;DR**

Is it reasonable to condense a series of short and very similar jobs into one entry on a resume?

**Details**

I am now in graduate school, and would like to make room on my resume for some recent (awesome) academic projects. I have four different internships on my resume from my undergraduate years that are very relevant to my current work search, but that had very similar projects. Would it be reasonable to condense them into one entry to save some space?

I'm thinking something like this:

> ## Internships
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   **Company A**    DateX - DateY    Location
>   **Company B**    DateX - DateY    Location
>   **Company C**    DateX - DateY    Location
>   **Company D**    DateX - DateY    Location
>
> - Project descriptions from the companies
> - Technologies used
> - Etc

I currently have the company name, employment dates, location, title, and project/responsibility descriptions for *every position*, so this layout would save me a lot of whitespace between the entries. Additionally, the earlier internships currently contain somewhat extraneous bullet points just because I don't like having a job entry with only one bullet point. This new layout would help me focus my descriptions on only the most important details without leaving awkward-looking job entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining them as you have suggested should be fine. It also makes it extra clear that these were internships; you weren't job-hopping.

Experienced recruiters will understand that your internships were during your undergraduate years, and intended to be short-term, but there would be no harm to add the phrase:

**Internships (while at Whatever University)**